# google drive sdk oath2 token

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm using Ruby quickstart.rb example script provided by https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ruby from a standalone ruby script running under Windows. The script works fine, it launches the browser window, I grant access to the app, paste the token in my console window and get authenticated.
My question is, how can I make this authentication process permanent or at least more long term? Currently I have to authorize the application every time I launch it.
Since the token changes every time a request is made, I'm not able to just save it in the script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use a service account and domain-wide delegation:

https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation